# Is there any good way to write the reference mark symbol ※ in MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

Consider the [reference mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_mark) symbol, ※, also pictured below:

[image: Reference mark]

What is the best way to write this symbol in MathJax?

Note that **I can copy-paste the symbol ※ directly**, but I think that this is not a good way and I am looking for a better way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MathJax, but the symbol is in unicode (※). Can you just print it as a unicode char?

Comment: Why not? As far as I can tell, MathJax is a JS library, and JS strings support unicode. You could either copy-paste the symbol directly, or I'm guessing you could use the JS escaped notation (`\u205C`). If those work but you don't consider them acceptable, please edit the question to add whatever constraints make them unacceptable.

Comment: @yshavit \u205C does not work. But anyway, I edited the question to make it more clear what I wanted.

Comment: 203B, not 205C. The edited question still does not answer why you don't think pasting the symbol directly is not a good way, nor does it answer why exactly `\ux203B` doesn't work (are you entering the text in HTML? then use `&#x203B;` instead). If you insist, maybe you can use the [`unicode` package](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/unicode.html), but I would definitely just paste the character itself.

Comment: Whoops, I copied the wrong code point. Thanks, @Amadan! @Amin, the reason we're asking "why" is that if you have a solution that provides the desired output, and you don't want to use it, then we assume there's some other constraint that makes the otherwise-working solution unacceptable. But if we don't know that constraint, it's hard to guess at an alternative that would work for you.

Comment: @yshavit The whole point of using mathjax is to avoid copy/pasting unicode characters directly.